# Django memoize per request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, memoization

I have a django rest application in which there is a function which calculates something using some external data (from another service) I want to avoid loading if not required. This data changes regularly, but is the same for one request. Therefore, I want to cache the result of this function (since it is called multiple times during one request) for the duration of exactly one request. I've come across the https://github.com/tvavrys/django-memoize/ library, which caches function results, but I can only specify a time and not a context after which the cache should be invalidated.

One possibility I found reasonable is to somehow register a hook which clears the cache after every request (using `delete_memoized`), but I have not found a method to register such a hook.

Therefore, my question is: Is it possible to either

- execute some code after a response has been rendered (→ clearing the cache), or
- tell django to cache a function result for exactly one request (using some other library?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should try with [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional)

> The @cached_property decorator caches the result of a method with a
>   single self argument as a property. The cached result will persist as
>   long as the instance does, so if the instance is passed around and the
>   function subsequently invoked, the cached result will be returned.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much :)